# Jenkins: Configure ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm Plugin using Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I'm currently spending some time setting up a generic configuration using Jenkins AD-SecurityRealm ([ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+plugin)) Plugin (v2.6) and stuck over a nasty issue: It seems that my approach to (auto) set up a valid AD-connection (following the corresponding [documentation](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/active-directory/hudson/plugins/active_directory/ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.html)) is not working at all. Every time I'll re-init my Jenkins instance an incomplete config.xml will provide - the "**bindName**" property (XML-node) is always missing. This property is required by the ad-server I'll use and so I've to override the config manually to solve this issue.

*I haven't the vaguest idea why this still happens*.

**my groovy code** (*excerpt*)

```
String _domain = 'my-primary-ad-server-running.acme.org'
String _site = 'jenkins.acme.org'
String _bindName = 'ad-bind-user'
String _bindPassword = 'ad-bind-password-super-secret-123'
String _server = 'my-primary-ad-server-running.acme.org'

def hudsonActiveDirectoryRealm = new ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm(_domain, _site, _bindName, _bindPassword, _server)

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
    instance.setSecurityRealm(hudsonActiveDirectoryRealm)
    instance.save()
```

**my config.xml result** (*excerpt*)

```
<securityRealm class="hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm" plugin="active-directory@2.6">
    <domains>
      <hudson.plugins.active__directory.ActiveDirectoryDomain>
        <name>my-primary-ad-server-running.acme.org</name>
        <servers>my-primary-ad-server-running.acme.org:3268</servers>
        <bindPassword>{###-fancy-crypted-super-password-nobody-can-decrypt-anymore-###}</bindPassword>
      </hudson.plugins.active__directory.ActiveDirectoryDomain>
    </domains>
    <startTls>true</startTls>
    <groupLookupStrategy>AUTO</groupLookupStrategy>
    <removeIrrelevantGroups>false</removeIrrelevantGroups>
    <tlsConfiguration>TRUST_ALL_CERTIFICATES</tlsConfiguration>
</securityRealm>
```

**my config.xml required** (*excerpt*)

```
<securityRealm class="hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm" plugin="active-directory@2.6">
    <domains>
      <hudson.plugins.active__directory.ActiveDirectoryDomain>
        <name>my-primary-ad-server-running.acme.org</name>
        <servers>my-primary-ad-server-running.acme.org:3268</servers>
        <bindName>ad-bind-user</bindName>
        <bindPassword>{###-fancy-crypted-super-password-nobody-can-decrypt-anymore-###}</bindPassword>
      </hudson.plugins.active__directory.ActiveDirectoryDomain>
    </domains>
    <startTls>true</startTls>
    <groupLookupStrategy>AUTO</groupLookupStrategy>
    <removeIrrelevantGroups>false</removeIrrelevantGroups>
    <tlsConfiguration>TRUST_ALL_CERTIFICATES</tlsConfiguration>
</securityRealm>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code for [ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm](https://github.com/jenkinsci/active-directory-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/active_directory/ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java#L163) you will see that the `bindName` is marked as transient, thus it won't be persisted as part of the config XML.

The only solution to get the desired config.xml is to force the config.xml by providing a custom static one and not use the init script.

Comment: I've tried to use a static xml before, but this file will be modified every time my jenkins is initialized again - so should I prevent using (all) init scripts at this point? _I'm using a few more beside my active-directory-setup one_.

Comment: I've updated my jenkins startUp process (removed all groovy init-scripts) and using a static config.xml now ... everything went fine now :)

Comment: @PatrickPaechnatz - how are you crypting the bindpassword in a way that is acceptable to Jenkins and isn't overwritten (thus modding the file and breaking a not_if ) on reboot ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @kosta.
Following script also works using active-directory 2.10 and jenkins 2.150.1
This also include site information.

```
import hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryDomain
import hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm
import hudson.plugins.active_directory.GroupLookupStrategy

String _domain = 'dev.test.com'
String _site = 'HQ'
String _bindName = 'dev\jenkins'
String _bindPassword = 'test'
String _server = 'dev.test.com:2328'

def hudsonActiveDirectoryRealm = new ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm(_domain, _site, _bindName, _bindPassword, _server)
hudsonActiveDirectoryRealm.getDomains().each({
    it.bindName = hudsonActiveDirectoryRealm.bindName
    it.bindPassword = hudsonActiveDirectoryRealm.bindPassword
    it.site = hudsonActiveDirectoryRealm.site
})
def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
instance.setSecurityRealm(hudsonActiveDirectoryRealm)
instance.save()
```

Check this screenshot: [Configure Global Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYmow.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by adding the following code at the end (Tested on 2.6 and 2.8). You also need to make sure that your credentials are valid because the plugin is doing an initial connectivity check https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48513

```
hudsonActiveDirectoryRealm.getDomains().each({
    it.bindName = hudsonActiveDirectoryRealm.bindName
    it.bindPassword = hudsonActiveDirectoryRealm.bindPassword
})
instance.setSecurityRealm(hudsonActiveDirectoryRealm)
instance.save()
```